# After one week, DNS A Records fail to update

Tags: domain-name-system

take a look at http://www.lorenzopierucci.com

About 1 week ago, the webmaster had updated the A records to point to my server, because his server was having issues.

However, it's been a week, and the site goes back and forth between returning the old server and the new server (I know this because I set a dummy index.html in the old server, saying:

```
Lorenzo Pierucci currently in the update process in your area.
```

Right now, when I ping it, it's returning --  67.205.16.244 ( the old server )

But, other times it's returning -- 198.20.229.197 , ( the new server )

Is this natural, or is there anything I can do to force the refresh?

It's a bit frustrating for me, since I don't feel this is my fault (I'm the web designer), but the blame is being moved over to me. But, enough complaining :P

I'd love anyone's assistance in helping me diagnose what is going on, and some directions on how to get this fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The webmaster needs to delete the old A record, not just add a new one.  It is behaving exactly as it's configured, with two addresses.

```
$ nslookup www.lorenzopierucci.com
Server:     192.168.156.10
Address:    192.168.156.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.lorenzopierucci.com
Address: 67.205.16.244
Name:   www.lorenzopierucci.com
Address: 198.20.229.197
```